# Can't submit form with "attributes" input field

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I have a form with the following setup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        @include('acp.sidebar')
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('acp/provider/add') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="id">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Grunddaten</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Beschreibung</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="url">Domain</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ref">Ref-Code</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ref" name="ref" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="image">Logo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control" accept="image/*">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="checkboxes">Payment-Anbieter</label>
                    <div>
                        @foreach($paymentProviders as $key => $provider)
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-{{$key}}">
                                <input name="paymentProviders[]" id="checkboxes-{{$key}}" value="{{$provider->id}}" type="checkbox">
                                <img src="{{url('/images/paymentProvider/small/'.$provider->image)}}">
                                {{$provider->name}}
                            </label>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Crawler</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="attributes">Suchattribute</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attributes" name="attributes" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="crawlerType">Typ</label>
                    <select id="crawlerType" name="crawlerType" class="form-control">
                        @foreach($crawlerTypes as $crawlerType)
                            <option value="{{$crawlerType}}">{{$crawlerType}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Absenden
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a input named "**attributes**" down below. When I add this, I can't submit my form. It's like clicking on a button with no "submit" attribute.

After removing or renaming this input, it works. It's not a big thing to rename my input - I'm just interested if this is a bug, or a for me unkown feature.

I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 and Laravel 5.4.22.

Comment: Reload the page and try again..

Comment: Like "reboot the device and wait 5 seconds"? ;) of course I tried this while debugging.. but there is definitely a problem with name/id = "attributes"

Comment: So you have the solution: Rename the button - seems to interfere with either bootstrap or Laravel - something you might see in the "view-source" or console

Comment: The button or the input? :) As mentioned it's no problem to rename it - i'm just interested why this happens. 
The "view-source" looks correct and the console output is empty.

Comment: Rename the form element named attributes. Here is a list from Eloquent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396741/reserved-column-names-in-eloquent

Comment: Yeah, I have already renamed it locally. 
But, as mentioned, I can't even submit my form. It's like clicking on a button without a type="submit" attribute.
There is not even an error.