# Laravel request works in Controller, but not in Model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a short problem and I can't understand why:

I have a form that POSTs data to a controller, where I call a function of the Model, in which I update the Model:

Controller:

```
public function vacancieEdit(EditVacancieRequest $request, Vacancie $vacancie)
    {
        $company = Company::find($vacancie->company_id);
        if ($company->userHasEditAccess()) {
            $vacancie->shortcutedit($request);
            return back();
        }
        return back()->with('message', 'Sie haben keine Rechte für diese Seite!');
    }
```

And in the model 'Vacancie' in which I update:

```
public function shortcutedit($request)
    {

        $company = Company::find(clean($request->company));

        if(!$company->userHasEditAccess() || !Branche::where('value', clean($request->branche))->exists()) {
            return false;
        }
        if(clean($request->visible) == 'on') {
            $visible = 1;
        } else {
            $visible = 0;
        }
        if (clean($request->siteapplication) == 'on') {
            $siteapplication = 1;
        } else {
            $siteapplication = 0;
        }
            $this->company_id = clean($request->company);
            $this->expdate = clean($request->expdate);
            $this->siteapplication = clean($request->siteapplication);
            $this->visible = $visible;
            $this->siteapplication = $siteapplication;
            $this->save();
    }
```

Everything is changing, except the 'visible' variable of the model.

However, if I place the code for visible in the Controller, the variable is changing. Why?

Code in Controller is working:

```
    if(clean($request->visible) == 'on') {
        $vacancie->visible = 1;
    } else {
        vacancie->visible = 0;
    }
    $vacancie->save();
```

How can I make it working in the Model?

---

Edit: I've edited the Vacancie Model to the following as suggested in Answer 1, but it is not working either.

```
public function shortcutedit($request)
    {

        $company = Company::find(clean($request->company));

        if(!$company->userHasEditAccess() || !Branche::where('value', clean($request->branche))->exists()) {
            return false;
        }
        if(clean($request->visible) == 'on') {
            $this->visible = 1;
        } else {
            $this->visible = 0;
        }
        if (clean($request->siteapplication) == 'on') {
            $siteapplication = 1;
        } else {
            $siteapplication = 0;
        }
            $this->company_id = clean($request->company);
            $this->title = clean($request->title, 'tinymce');
            $this->branche = clean($request->branche);
            $this->text = clean($request->text);
            $this->visible = clean($request->visible);
            $this->startdate = clean($request->startdate);
            $this->expdate = clean($request->expdate);
            $this->siteapplication = clean($request->siteapplication);

            $this->siteapplication = $siteapplication;

            $this->save();
    }
```

Comment: The flow isn't right, but lets try to solve the issue anyway.

Try change $request->visible to $request->input('visible')

Comment: In your `Vacancie` Model, shouldn't `$vacancie` be `$this`? Currently, that's `undefined`. You don't pass or instantiate `$vacancie` anywhere in your `shortcutedit` method.

Comment: When I call `$vacancie->shortcutedit` , I use $this to refer to the Vacancie I created at the function call in the controller. Or do I think there wrong?

Comment: Read @TimLewis reply, he seems to be right.

Comment: `$vacancie->save();` being called in `shortcutedit` might be throwing an error. It looks like a carry over from your controller snippet `($vacancie->visible = ...; $vacancie->save();`). You can probably just remove `$vacancie->save();` since you're setting `$this->visible = $visible; ... $this->save();` later.

Comment: @TimLewis The third code block is the logic that is working if I put it into the controller. Only the second code block is the vacancie model. I cant find the `$vacancie` in the vacancie model. In the controller I have the `$vacancie` from the functioncall.

Comment: @TimLewis that first `$vacancie->save` was a mistake I made copying the code into stack overflow. I dont have it in my real code. Ups :)

Comment: In that case, not sure what's up. At a glance, that looks like it should work fine. Do some debugging; maybe `clean($request->visible)` or `$visible` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: The thing thats confusing me is that the code is working fine, if executed in the Controller

Comment: As suggested, debug $request->input('visible') and see what you get in the controller and in the model?

Comment: It is "on" if I tick it or "" if I dont tick it, so it seems to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Reserved column names in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396741/reserved-column-names-in-eloquent)

No idea how it is working from the Controller.

There is a `protected $visible` attribute in the Model to hide/show attributes when invoking `toArray` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

What happens when you change `$this->visible` with `$this->attributes['visible']` ?

Comment: As in the controller, vacancie->visible references $this->attributes['visible'].

Comment: Thank you very much, thats the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code:

```
public function shortcutedit($request)
{

    $company = Company::find(clean($request->company));

    if ( !$company->userHasEditAccess() || !Branche::where('value', clean($request->branche))->exists()) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->attributes['company_id'] = clean($request->company);
    $this->attributes['title'] = clean($request->title, 'tinymce');
    $this->attributes['branche'] = clean($request->branche);
    $this->attributes['text'] = clean($request->text);
    $this->attributes['visible'] = (clean($request->input('visible')) == 'on') ? 1 : 0;
    $this->attributes['startdate'] = clean($request->startdate);
    $this->attributes['expdate'] = clean($request->expdate);
    $this->attributes['siteapplication'] = (clean($request->input('siteapplication')) == 'on') ? 1 : 0;

    $this->save();
}
```

Comment: Or don't even use `$this->save();` in that spot, there since it's used later in the function.

Comment: Try the revised version

Comment: That ? if statement... Man, thank you, that makes it so cool!

Answer (score 0):

So, in your edit, you've indicated that you're performing this `if()` check:

```
if(clean($request->visible) == 'on') {
  $this->visible = 1;
} else {
  $this->visible = 0;
}
```

and setting `$this->visible` to `1` or `0`, but you're then promptly overriding it below with:

```
$this->visible = clean($request->visible);
```

So, at the end of this function, when `$this->save();` is called, `$this->visible` will be either `null` or `"on"`.

Remove the second setting of `$this->visible = clean($request->visible);` and this should work for you.

Comment: I am so stupid... I've removed it, but nothing changed... I don't understand the world. I've cleared the cache, but nope..

But Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not stupid; we all miss stuff like that. Just try to be aware of the code you write, maybe use an IDE (might catch duplicate assignment, etc)